# Linux - Error loading rJava in Rstudio: libjvm.so: missing?

Tags: linux, rstudio, xlsx, rjava

i just installed Rstudio and wanted some packaes to use, im using linux mint, when i tried to install the xlsx package give an error related to rjava, so i installed the rjava package, but it cant be loaded, instead i get this error:

```
>library("rJava", lib.loc="/usr/lib/R/site-library")
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/site-
library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
>detach("package:rJava", unload=TRUE)
Error in detach("package:rJava", unload = TRUE) : invalid 'name' 
argument
```

I tried R CMD javareconf several times, but still no clue of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to locate the library, you can use the `whereis` command or look into standard path which are :

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server`

Once it's located, copy its folder's path.

Then add it to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable located in `~/.profile` (create the file if needed).

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server`

> If you already have a LD_LIBRARY_PATH set you may want to keep it, so `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and add its content into the `~/.profile` file.

You can reboot to reload the .profile, or you can just `source ~/.profile` form a terminal.

To conclude just `sudo R CMD javareconf`.

Comment: after, whereis java i got--> java: /usr/bin/java /usr/local/java /usr/share/java, i remeber once removed openjdk and installed java instead , not sure which of the 3 folders should i use

Comment: current java version:
 "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: I meant `whereis libjvm.so`

Comment: When I do that I get: "user@User-PC:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle$ whereis libjvm.so
libjvm: "
?

Comment: `whereis` didn't find anything here, but `find / -name libjvm.so` did.